# How do I get my baby blue tongue skinks to get used to being held?

Tags: training, lizards

When ever I try to pick them up they tend to run away. They have never hissed or bitten me, but I would like to be able to hold them.

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea about lizards, but I would guess they end up being like any other pet or human in this regard.

Would you like a foreign person to grab you and put you on their lab or carry you somewhere else? No? Then what is with a child that even asks to be held by their parents? That's different.

With someone you trust, being held or pet or cuddled is a nice thing. That is not only because you know they won't harm you, but also because you know that they know and acknowledge your boundaries. Which means, if you want them to stop, they will stop.

For your lizards that means you will have to earn their trust. With rabbits you could feed them out of your hands, sit in the room while they run around and let them sniff and discover you at **their** pace. 
I am sure there are some similar options for lizards. Just try to be close, but never intrusive.
Then you can try petting them, if you think they would be comfortable with it. As soon as they look uncomfortable, stop!

Bit by bit, both of you will get to know each other, earn each others trust and learn to read the signs given by each other. You will know that you won't be bitten (unless you don't read the signs and go on after your pet is uncomfortable) and your pet will know there is no reason to run away or bite (unless you behave strangely and carry that box with the veterinarian smell on it).